# Can the covariance matrix in a Gaussian Process be non-symmetric?

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process

I was watching a lecture on Gaussian Process and when the covariance matrix was introduced, the tutor [explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpsV1y6wMQ8&feature=youtu.be&t=1130) that the matrix is $(n \times n)$ because every point is covered twice - we include the information about the covariance of $(x_1, x_2)$ and about the covariance of $(x_2, x_1)$. She then said: *that's because your covariance can vary in different directions*.

How is it possible that the *covariances can vary in different directions* inside the GP covariance matrix? Could you give me an example of when that could be the case?

**Update:**

After giving it some thought, I realized that it is not $cov(x_1, x_2)$ or $cov(x_2, x_1)$ (as computed from the definition of covariance) that go into the GP covariance matrix, but instead (as was shown in the lecture as well), the covariance matrix is populated by a covariance kernel $k(x, y)$ that acts/is interpreted **as a covariance**, but it is some function of the distance between $x$ and $y$.

I could therefore imagine, that we might have a covariance kernel that is a function of $(x - y)^p$ where $p$ is an odd power. In such instance, it would indeed make $k(x_1, x_2) \neq k(x_2, x_1)$. **But would this be a valid kernel?**

Could you clarify if my thinking about the covariance kernel is reasonable? Could you explain if the covariance matrix in Gaussian Process can be non-symmetric? If yes, could you give an example of a dataset where it would make sense to make covariance different in different directions, i.e. where we would like $k(x_1, x_2)$ to be different from $k(x_2, x_1)$?

Comment: You are right, they are never different. The lady is wrong.

Comment: I am giving it some thought and I have a possible explanation why it might make sense. The covariance matrix does not really contain $cov(x, y)$ but instead, it is populated by a function $k(x, y)$ that "acts" as a covariance (it is later interpreted as a covariance between $x$ and $y$, however, the function can indeed take a different value for $k(x, y)$ and $k(y, x)$). Since in the lecture it was said that the covariance kernel is a function of distance between $x$ and $y$, it might indeed make sense for kernels where there is $x - y$ raised to an odd power. Does my reasoning make sense?

Comment: In a gaussian process, the matrix $K(x_1, x_2)$ is always used as a covariance matrix for a multivariate normal, hence, it _**must**_ be symmetric.

Comment: @InfProb These comments appear to be applying two completely different senses of "symmetric." The first sense is that $K(x_i,x_j)$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Specifically, $K(x_i,x_j)_{rs}=K(x_j,x_i)_{sr}$ for all $1\le r,s\le n.$  As you point out it must be, because it's a covariance matrix.  The second sense--which I believe is the one used in this question--is that $K(x_i,x_j)=K(x_j,x_i)$ for all $i,j.$  This is decidedly *not* implied by the defining properties of a Gaussian process.

Comment: @whuber Could you please post an example of such an assymetric function? Don't kernel functions _have_ to be symmetric [as in this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics))?

Comment: @InfProbSciX Don't overlook Wikipedia's qualifier "For most applications..."  There's no inherent mathematical necessity that kernels be symmetric.  For instance, an exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA) of a time series is a windowed mean using an asymmetric kernel.

Comment: Related ideas here that I just hit in a paper involving assymetric kernels. I think it is a mechanistic stretch to call these "Gaussian Processes" and I trying to understand if these are actually some causual random field or maybe ther eis a simpler way of thinking about it 

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546688/assymetric-kernels-in-gaussian-process-regression

Comment: @whuber Interesting ... I think this point might come down to "all the calculations can still work with an assymetric matrix but it's not a gaussian anymore"

Comment: @Mathtick You seem to confuse two separate concepts: In a Gaussian process, all finite-dimensional marginal distributions are Gaussian; but the kernel describes how those distributions vary with the spatial configuration.  That's a separate issue.

Comment: @whuber I posted a screenshot of a canoncical definition. I think you may be on to something in describing the confusion but I think the typical definition of GP is symmetric in the full sense i.e. the kernel is a Mercer kernel. It is like a brownian sheet. If the kernel is $K(x, x') = \langle Y(x), Y(x')\rangle$ then it should be symmetric in $x, x'$.

Comment: @mathtick This might be a matter of what community one works within.  In the spatial statistics literature such asymmetric "kernels" are contemplated, but often the simplifying assumption of symmetry is quickly made.  Spatio-temporal modeling is a natural area of applications where asymmetric kernels can be expected, so ruling them out would just be unconstructive.

Comment: @whuber Right so I think we are saying assymetric "kernels" are not kernels, they do not correspond to 2nd order statistics of Gaussian Processes. It is a misnomer. It just happens to be useful to start with GPs and the usual definition of symmetric kernels and extend to assymetric case without interpretation.

Answer (score 10):

> Can the covariance matrix in a Gaussian Process be non-symmetric?

Every valid covariance matrix is a real symmetric non-negative definite matrix.  This holds regardless of the underlying distribution.  So no, it can't be non-symmetric.  If the lecturers are making an argument for using some non-symmetric matrix (e.g., using a non-symmetric kernel) in a way that "acts/is interpreted as a covariance" somehow, then the onus is on them to explain how far this analogy holds, given that the matrix is not a valid covariance matrix.

Comment: Although this (correctly) answers the question in the title, it is not relevant to the question as expressed in the body of the post.

Comment: Just a side note for novice readers, non-symmetric Kernel (covariance functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Covariance_functions ) and non-symmetric covariance matrix are not the same thing.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen  There is no non-symmetric covariance matrix. I think the semantics are getting even more confusing surrounding this question. And covariance function should really be some bilinear symmetric form or whatever right?

Comment: @mathtick Definitely, you are right. Semantics could get more confusing, specially if it applied in cross disciplinary fields.

Answer (score 0):

Answering below in order to be able to post a screen shot in response to a comment, this is not an answer to the question.

[image: Kevin Murphy]