# What would be the interpretation of asymmetric kernels in Gaussian Process Regression?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, gaussian-process

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06952) involves with asymmetric Kernels. They claim  that this arises due to local parameters. But this is not really true. They induce a particular asymmetric structure in the Kernel yet still call these "Gaussian processes".

What is an interpretation of this that makes sense? It isn't really a Gaussian process any more: it seems like one interpretation is that they are inducing some causal graph (directed instead of undirected random field) that gives rise to this asymmetric structure. This is just a guess.

Is there any better way to see how this is still somehow a "Gaussian Process" even thought the kernel (covariance function) is not symmetric?

Comment: See here for related material https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375035/can-the-covariance-matrix-in-a-gaussian-process-be-non-symmetric

Comment: This asymmetry is not related to causality.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen what do you mean not related? I am looking for a model with Gaussian innovations that gives rise to this structure in the condition probabilities. I thought of a dag causal structure as I think any simple random Gaussian field should have symmetric kernel?

Comment: Definitely, you are absolutely right. DAGs are promising in building causal structures.  I was only referring to this particular paper that they did not address causality explicitly.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen Yes they did not, but they also seem to be saying things that are not semantically correct. They basically take a GPR "calculation", make the kernel asymmetric, invert using SVD instead of Cholesky or other methods for p.d. matrices, and call this "GPR". 

But I don't think it is actually a Gaussian Process anymore since the kernel is assymetric. So we are left trying to find the model that their algorithm implies.

Comment: Interesting. True, this is probably not a vanilla GPR anymore.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen Yes I think either I am completely missing something or they are basically falling into the typical ML/eng pattern of confounding algo with model. So they start with a GP, write down the calc. Call the *calc/algo* the "GPR" now as oppose to the model the "GPR". Change something in the calc, and then use the "GPR" label even though the calc is not a GPR at all anymore. It is natural and good way to do things of course, but confusing in terms of labels, meaning and intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert, but to my understanding their approach would break the PSD constraint on the corresponding covariance matrix. They don't address this in their paper at all. Like you mentioned, they call it a GP, but all they are using from the GP is the weighted sum portion that pertains to the mean. They ignore the covariance completely.